# Selenium Webdriver support for Safari

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Visual Studio 2013.  Here is some information:

- .Net Framework 4.6
- Webdriver 2.53.1.0
- Webdriver support 2.53.1.0
- Safari extension 2.48.0

I am trying to run Selenium functional UI code against a web app called by the browser using C#.  For some reason, I am having an issue with the Safari Driver.  I have followed everything implemented here:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver?__s=mp3r6zbqyk5tjvokqx7q#getting-started?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=elemental-selenium-java&utm_source=69-safari

Please help. I do not know what I am missing.

**Here is the exception detail:**

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Did not receive a connection from the Safari extension. Please verify that it is properly installed and is the proper version.
>     Source=WebDriver
>     StackTrace:
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriverServer.Start()
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriver..ctor(SafariOptions options)
>          at OpenQA.Selenium.Safari.SafariDriver..ctor()
>          at Symphony.AutomationFramework.Browser.GoToApp(String baseURL) in c:\Users\amaddox\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Experiment\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Symphony.AutomationFramework\Browser.cs:line 57
>          at Symphony.AcceptanceTests.Hooks.Hooks.GotToApp() in c:\Users\amaddox\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Experiment\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Symphony.AcceptanceTests\Hooks\Hooks.cs:line 34
>          at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
>     InnerException:

[safari extension installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGztW.png)

Comment: Try backing up to Selenium 2.47.0

Comment: How do I do that from within Visual Studio?

Comment: Click on solution, managenuget packages, then click on the project with selenium installed, you should see and uninstall button, or if you see other versions in install list select those versions and reinstall.  If you uninstall first, you have to re-add Selenium to the list of packages to install.  Note you can do this by Nuget command line too.